# iOS data doesn't seem to be saving to NSURLCache

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, nsurlcache

So I am creating a custom cache file via NSURLCache via the following method in my AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
NSURLCache  *result = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:MBYTE(20) diskCapacity:MBYTE(200) diskPath:@"URLCache"];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:result];
```

where MBYTE is defined as :

```
#ifndef MBYTE
#define MBYTE(x)   ((x) << 20)
#endif
```

Then later on I am saving a `NSCachedURLResponse` in the `NSURLCache` in the following method:

```
  NSURLCache *sharedCache = [NSURLCache sharedURLCache];
                        [sharedCache storeCachedResponse:cachedResponse forRequest:theRequest];
```

When I run the code I seem to be able to pull up the response and find it in cache and it seems to work. However, when I try and see how much cache has been used on launch via:

`[result currentDiskUsage]` or `[result currentMemoryUsage]`
the NSLog always returns 0. Even though I am able to load the response via the cache.

So I am wondering if this is something I should worry about, maybe